How to get a single character from a `String[]` in vyper
Let's say I want to get the h from my_string
@external
@view
def loop() -> String[1]:
    my_string: String[5] = "hello"
    return my_string[1]

How would I do this?

You can use slice:
@external
@view
def loop() -> String[1]:
    my_string: String[5] = "hello"
    return slice(my_string, 0, 1)

